# Hibernate : stange error when using the IN clause in sub select query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm, jpql

Using hibernate 4.3.11.final.

We make a request with @Query annotation where we use a **in** clause in a sub select query ex :

```
select distinct doc from DocumentType doc join doc.usages u where u.institute not in :institutes and doc.id not in (select distinct doc1.id from DocumentType doc1 join doc1.usages u1 where u1.institute in :institutes)
```

The first in clause is correctly generated (with surrounding parenthesis added) but the one in the subselect is not.

The generated sql is :

```
select distinct doc from fr.itce.pen.model.customer.folder.DocumentType doc join doc.usages u where u.institute not in (:institutes_0_, :institutes_1_) and doc.id not in (select distinct doc1.id from fr.itce.pen.model.customer.folder.DocumentType doc1 join doc1.usages u1 where u1.institute in :institutes_0_, :institutes_1_)]
```

A work around is to surround the in part with parenthesis in the declared query as :

```
select distinct doc from DocumentType doc join doc.usages u where u.institute not in :institutes and doc.id not in (select distinct doc1.id from DocumentType doc1 join doc1.usages u1 where u1.institute in (:institutes))
```

Is there a better way to make it work, and / or is this 'bug' fixed in recent hibernate versions? I looked at hibernate issues but i was unable to find any information about this behaviour.

Best regards.

Comment: Seems to me as i'm bitten by https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5126?focusedCommentId=62841&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-62841

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's a bug, but it will not be fixed in 4.3.

You need to replicate it on 5.2 with a test case and the open a Jira issue.

Comment: hum we pass a List<Institute> to the request so i guess we respect this aspect but maybe i don't anderstand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It was a bug, it's corrected with hibernate 5.2.